# How to captuare an IP packet, change its content and resend it on Linux?

Tags: linux, ip, packet

My question is:

How to captuare an incoming IP packet from a network interface, change its content and resend it from another network interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The choice is yours, there is no preference (and hence no "normal").

- using libnetfilter_queue to deliver to userspace and do extensive modification there.
- or an xtables module, also works (since it's called by NF anyway). Allows for sufficient fine-grained configuration with help from userspace.
- nfhook module, if you must. All configuration you must implement yourself.
- well and finally, if you like things that hurt, you might as well implement your own virtual NIC driver.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way of doing something like this is to create a [netfilter hook module](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//netfilter-hacking-HOWTO.html).

See [this example](http://www.paulkiddie.com/2009/11/creating-a-netfilter-kernel-module-which-filters-udp-packets/) for a quick start.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what you intend to change exactly, which makes it difficult to answer your question properly.

For content substitution on a router kind of device (guess), *netsed* might be the simplest approach available.